# Who instantiates the test class in a test class project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, activator

I am writing some integration tests. I am using Dependency Injection with Windsor Castle.

I would like to resolve the test class using an inversion of control container. I do not think that resolve all my dependencies inside the test class is the solution for my case.

I would like to do what I have done inside the web api project. I implemented `IHttpControllerActivator`, which is an extension point to fully control controller's life-cycle. That is, we can define how a controller is instantiated.

I would like to do the same for the tests. But I do not understand which is the interface I have to implement. Can anyone help me?

I think I just need to know which is the corresponding `IHttpControllerActivator` for unit test.

**EDIT**

I have a web api project to test. The web api project resolves all the  dependencies with WindsorCastle. Now I need to test the web api. This is what I am doing:

```
public voi MyTest_Ok()
{
    //Arrange

    var myController = new MyWebApiController();
    var result = await myController.DoWork();

    //Asserts
}
```

Obviously it does not work because I am not using castle windsor to resolve the controller and so I do not resolve any dependency from web api controller to bottom.

I think I could replace this line

```
var myController = new MyWebApiController();
```

with something like this

```
var myController = windsorContainer.Resolve<MyWebApiController>();
```

But this solution I think is wrong. I think it's better to resolve dependencies as happen inside the controller:

```
public class MyWebApiController : ApiController()
{
    public InjectedDependency dep { get; set; }

    public DoWork()
    {
        dep.DoWork();
    }
}
```

I can do this because I have implemented a custom `IHttpControllerActivator`.

Comment: Unit testing a class with injected dependencies will always mock the dependencies. No need for any injection library at all.

Comment: I see 2 contraindications in your answer... 1) I have different injected dipendencies and I want to mock just one per time. I would like to define again only the mocked dipendency, not all.... 2) If I resolve in my test class the dipendencies I must reference windsor castle to my test project... I hope I have been clear

Comment: Unit test is just testing a single method of a single class. Anything else needs to be mocked. Otherwise you are not doing a **unit test**.

Comment: you are right... perhaps the correct term is **integration test**... I correct my post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NUnit integration tests and dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933983/nunit-integration-tests-and-dependency-injection)

Comment: No... I Am asking exactly how to avoid that! I do not want to resolve dependencies inside the test... I think I need to understand who instanciate my test class.

Comment: "use its own dependency injection approach". What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: your test framework does. As I know none of the common test frameworks allows you take control over creating your test classes.

More info about this here as well:

[A .NET Unit Test without a parameterless constructor, to facilitate dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373592/a-net-unit-test-without-a-parameterless-constructor-to-facilitate-dependency-i)

NUnit provide ParameterizedTestFixture -https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestFixtureData

So in theory as a dirty workaround you would be able to inject some dependencies trough constructor by this, but it wasn't designed for this purpose.

In general you have to go for service locator.